# how to using keyboard to select data in treeview without mouse

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

Firstly, When my cursor is in the entry box (`entrybox.focus()`),  I would like to using F4 key on keyboard (`GUI.bind('<F4>',  directselection)`) to select the first data in my treeview directly instead of using mouse.

I don't have any idea to create the function. I'm trying to use

```
def directselection(event = None):
    treeviewtable.focus()
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.get_children()` to get a list of row IDs and then use `.selection_set()` to select the first row:

```py
def directselection(event=None):
    # get all row IDs
    idlist = treeviewtable.get_children()
    if idlist:
        # select and focus on first row
        treeviewtable.selection_set(idlist[0])
        treeviewtable.focus(idlist[0])
        # transfer keyboard focus to treeviewtable
        treeviewtable.focus_force()
```

Comment: thank you! It's work.
but the cursor is still focus on the entrybox if you don't mind please help :)